# SassKit.Multitenancy not compatible with AspNetCore 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a .NET Core API Controller, and in the POST method, I'm trying to use the [CreatedAtActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_CreatedAtAction_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) method to include the route as a Location Header in my response.

```
[ApiController, Route("v1/[controller]")]
public class WidgetController: ControllerBase
{
    public WidgetController(IWidgetService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    private readonly IWidgetService _service;

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetSingle")]
    public IActionResult GetSingle(Guid id)
    {
        var result = _service.Get(id);

        return Ok(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(WidgetModel model)
    {
        var result = _service.Post(model);

        return result == Guid.Empty
                    ? (IActionResult) BadRequest("No changes saved.")
                    : CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSingle),
                                      new {id = result},
                                      model);
    }
}
```

When I start the application, the first call to POST from POSTman runs without problem. Both the object and the Location Header URL get generated as expected. However, if I try to hit that endpoint a second time while the code is still running, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointAddressScheme`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValuesAddress]' has been registered.
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultLinkGenerator.GetEndpoints[TAddress](TAddress address)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultLinkGenerator.GetPathByAddress[TAddress](HttpContext httpContext, TAddress address, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteValueDictionary ambientValues, Nullable`1 pathBase, FragmentString fragment, LinkOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGeneratorRouteValuesAddressExtensions.GetPathByRouteValues(LinkGenerator generator, HttpContext httpContext, String routeName, Object values, Nullable`1 pathBase, FragmentString fragment, LinkOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.EndpointRoutingUrlHelper.Action(UrlActionContext urlActionContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper helper, String action, String controller, Object values, String protocol, String host, String fragment)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper helper, String action, String controller, Object values, String protocol, String host)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at SaasKit.Multitenancy.Internal.TenantResolutionMiddleware`1.Invoke(HttpContext context, ITenantResolver`1 tenantResolver)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I have tried swapping out the `CreatedAtAction` with an `Ok`, and that 200 result will return as many times as I click the button in POSTman.

The code inside the `Post` method successfully processes, and it will move onto the `OnActionExecuted` method of a Filter that I created. I've tried looking through all of the properties of the `ActionExecutedContext` object and I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Once I get out of that empty `OnActionExecuted` method, the call returns the 500 status code and the above stack trace inside the error page. I do have an Exception filter, but that doesn't get touched.

Has anyone had issues with this before?

For reference, here is my Startup Configuration:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, CachingAppTenantResolver>();

    services.AddAutoMapper()
            .AddSingleton(ConfigureAutoMapper())
            .AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<ValidatorActionFilter>();
                options.Filters.Add<ErrorHandlingFilter>();
            })
            .AddFluentValidation(validation => {
                validation.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
                validation.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                validation.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<WidgetModelValidator>();
                })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
                options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
            });

    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>();

    services.Configure<MultitenancyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Multitenancy"));

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

    ConfigureContainer(container);

    return provider;
}
```

Comment: I haven't; but is it possible that also posting your Startup.ConfigureServices() might be relevant? A bug for the second call surely makes us think that service lifetime is involved. And/or perhaps there is some gotcha with the new EndpointPointRouting

Comment: Good point. I forgot to include that. Thank you, @ChrisFCarroll

Comment: So I could be barking up the wrong tree here, but my next diagnostic step would be, remove the 2 suspects for "holding information across calls" : remove the CachingAppTenantResolver and make the singleton AutoMapper a transient dependency instead. And see if that gets you a different error message?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll I understand what you're going for. I was able to remove the singleton for AutoMapper, and that did not help. Removing the Multitenancy thing is going to be a giant can of worms to unwind, and we do need that for our app. I can give that a shot though later if we can't find anything else.

Comment: @RistoM Yes, the Post method does compile. That was a typo when I typed the code over here to avoid any names of internal code.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative to removing the multitenancy thing is just, looking through it can you see any clues as to, might it be holding on to something across calls that could possibly mess up the service registration?

Comment: Another idea: What happens when you try CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_0 or 2.1 instead of 2.2? (EndpointRouting only came with 2.2, and your controller should just work as is under 2.1 or 2.0). If your tenancy stuff is a 3rd party thing, it might not yet be compatible with 2.2?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll That Compatibility Version issue was it! If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. I did still have the Singleton for AutoMapper and left the Multitenancy alone. I wonder if I should send this as a bug over to Microsoft, or if it is the `SassKit.Multitenancy` library that's causing the actual issue. I think I'll make a dummy project without Multitenancy to test that out.

Comment: With that simple app to test, the `CreatedAtAction` worked on successive calls using 2.2. I guess it does have something to do with `SassKit.Multitenancy`. Checking out the GitHub for the project, it hasn't been updated in 3 years. :/

Comment: MS are still soliciting bugs & feedback on Endpoint routing -- they might still be glad of a bug report. It think t was intended to be backwards compatible

Comment: I'll pass that along. Thanks again for figuring that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_0` or `2.1` instead of `2.2`?

EndpointRouting is quite a big change under the covers of 2.2, and your 3rd party add-on might not be compatible.

Setting compatibility back to 2.1  will typically not require any code changes in your controller, so it's fairly low-cost.